# Comparing :new value inserted with a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, triggers, database-trigger

I'm trying to build a trigger that checks if the row that is gonna be inserted, exists in another table.

Basically my 2 tables share one column, ID.
I want to prevent the insertion when the new row doesnt exist at least once in the other table.

I have this:

```
create or replace trigger BIM
before insert on TABLE1 
for each row
begin
    if not exists (select 1 from TABLE2 where TABLE2.ID = :new.TABLE1.ID)
then
    raise_application_error(-20634, 'Error');
  end if;
end;
```

But i'm getting this:

```
PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.TABLE1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon is right, It is preferable to use Foreign Key constraint for this scenario.

The problem with your code ( apart from the error which Gordon pointed out )is that unlike few other DBMS like Postgres, In Oracle you cannot use `EXISTS` in a PL/SQL expression/statements like `IF`. It should be a purely SQL statement.

```
create or replace trigger BIM
before insert on TABLE1 
 for each row
declare 
l_id_exists INT;
begin
    select CASE WHEN 
                 exists (select 1 from TABLE2 where TABLE2.ID = :new.ID) 
             THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 END INTO l_id_exists from dual;
   if l_id_exists = 0
   then
    raise_application_error(-20634, 'Error');
  end if;
end;
/
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=948fda90d1bf9f522a14fbcaba596f08)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the table name:

```
create or replace trigger BIM
before insert on TABLE1 
for each row
begin
    if (select 1 from TABLE2 where TABLE2.ID = :new.ID and rownum = 0) is not null
then
    raise_application_error(-20634, 'Error');
  end if;
end;
```

That said, this is an odd requirement.  I would recommend that you use a foreign key constraint, but you explicitly say "at least once".  That leads me to suspect that you have a bad data model -- you are missing some sort of entity where the `id` would be the primary key of that table.

Comment: Well it is not a bad model, I'm supposed to create an assertion that checks if every new record on table 1, exists in table 2. Btw I tried your code and its correct but now I'm getting the following error: `Errors: TRIGGER BIM Line/Col: 2/5 PL/SQL: Statement ignored Line/Col: 2/12 PLS-00204: function or pseudo-column 'EXISTS' may be used inside a SQL statement only`

Comment: @KekaBron . . . You should use a foreign key constraint.